# The Stanley Parable weird blue hallway

Tags: the-stanley-parable

In this video i find an odd room with a blue hallway where the two doors room is supposed to be. I can't find anything but the blue spawn office if i try to search it up. Can anyone help me? This is the first time i've ever seen this.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Help you with what?